# Google map api not loading in the localhost, routing using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui-router

So I've been trying to load a google map on my page, and it works fine on my website, but when I run in my localhost I can't see the map and there are no errors in the console.  I made sure to check that my api key accepts requests from localhost.  I also suspect ui-router might cause a problem because it's one of the last things I changed, but I made sure that all the parent divs of the map have sizes of 100% of the page.  Any advice?

Main page (I load all my angular libraries here but they're not shown to save space)

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="parentController" id="framebody">

    <div ui-view name="navbar"></div>
    <div ui-view name="content" id="view1"></div>

</body>
```

/browse page loaded with ui-router:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
</script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAbdhjG6qnDknBLfRXWoevbcEe8aEt7F08&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

App.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'mgo-angular-wizard',
  'ngDialog',
  'ui.router',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngFileUpload',
  'angularCSS'
]);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $stateProvider

    .state('browse', {
      url: '/browse',

      views: {
        navbar: {
          css: '/css/nav.css',
          templateUrl: '/navbar',
        },
        content: {
          templateUrl: '/browse',
          controller: 'browseController',
          css: '/css/browse.css'
        }
      }
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse');

}]);
```

Comment: What about the page itself, `browseController` associated with the page is loading properly ?

Comment: yea it is loading correctly... there are no other errors that show up.

Comment: weird.. My guess was the browse page itself was not opened... What about the `initMap` callback ? It should be called once the script is loaded. try adding a `console.log` to see if it works.

Comment: I know that the browse page opens bc I have other divs in the actual version that do show up...  Looks like if I put the div directly in the main page I get an ApiNotActivatedMapError from google.  But I checked and it looks like its is activated with localhost accepted...